# getReferrer function returns caller package name only if called app wasn't in background before

Tags: android

There are already many questions on "How to retrieve the packagename of the caller app" available and most of them refers to the function:

[getReferrer()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getReferrer())

This works perfectly if the called app isn't in the background, but if it is, then the function will return the Uri of the called app and not the caller.

So my further question is: Is it even possible to guarantee to get the callers packagename? (Assuming that the caller is not spoofing the packagename and calling the app only as usual with startActivity without adding or modifying the intent extras.)